# Configuration properties using the same key to create an array / list

Tags: java, arrays, configuration, properties

I would like to store the source for html select boxes in a configuration file. These contain a lengthy strings that don't change often (but occassionaly do):

- Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 1
- Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 2
- Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 3
- Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 4

I already use commons-configuration. Is it possible to store them using the same property keys in some kind of configuration object (XMLConfiguration, HierarchicalConfiguration, etc.)? I mean to be able to retrieve them in one go using interface similar to [getStringArray()](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration.html#getStringArray%28java.lang.String%29) (or list)? Example:

```
// reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 1
// reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 2
// reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 3
// reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 4

config.getStringArray(reject.reason)
```

I don't want to keep them separated on the same line because, first, the reasons are lengthy, and second, there are lots of reasons (> 10).

I don't want to store them in enums either, b/c it will be impossible to change them without recompiling the code.

Any hints on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your example looks fine to me. If you specify a list of values using the same key, they are treated as a list, and the following should work:

```
reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 1
reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 2
reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 3
reject.reason = Lorem ipsum sit amet nr. 4
```

In your Java code:

```
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration("gui.properties");
String[] reasons = config.getStringArray("reject.reason");
```

http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_properties.html#Lists_and_arrays

Comment: Great, thanks, dogbane! Do you know if commons-configuration has some support for UTF-8 encoded resource bundles by any chance?

Answer (score 4):

You could store them in a .properties file and name as ...

```
key.0=line0  
key.1=line1  
key.2=line2
```

Then in your code iterate through properties with a for loop looking for `"key." + i` until you get a null back.

I have done this in the past to enumerate and configure com ports and it works well.

Comment: That's what I was writing :) You could even wrap the standard Configuration object in your own wrapper which does this for you.

Comment: Right, that was my first thought as well. I just can't believe there isn't a ready solution for this use case out there. Furthermore, I feel it's already provided by commons-configuration and I just can't find a clear info on how to get it. I'll just try with my gut and will just use the above mentioned now.